# opencv: show an image and wait for variable to change, instead of waiting for a keypress

Tags: infinite-loop, sleep, keypress, opencv, python

I have a generative system that continually generates images forever - It generates a new image maybe every second or two, but it isn't consistent.

I want to display each new image as it's output from the system, and I want to display that image until the system outputs another image, which I'll then display instead. The result would look like a continuous stream of generated images.

The problem is that cv2 requires me to put in "waitKey" - which will either wait for a number of milliseconds or until a key is pressed. If I don't include "waitKey" - the image will instantly disappear as soon as it's displayed.

Is there any way to have cv2 display an image until a variable is updated?

Right now my code looks like:

```
while True:
        finalimage = generate_image() # this part takes a second, give or take.
        cv2.imshow("window", finalimage)
        cv2.waitKey(2000)
```

But that requires me to wait 2 seconds for each image... which can be sped up. Also - if there's a case where generating the image takes over 2 seconds, the script would screw up.

**TLDR: is there any way to show an image with cv2 indefinitely until a variable is updated/changed- without pausing the program to wait for key input?**

Comment: you can update finalimage in a separate thread, and let OpenCV imshow/waitkey in the main thread running, this keeps your interface responsive and shows the image as soon as possible. You can put a waitkey of 100ms so that it shows your new image when it is ready

Answer (score 1):

The normal way is to separate the GUI part from the part that generates the image. To do that just put the generation in another thread. Here is a small sample code of how to do that.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time # not really needed, used to simulate the 2 seconds of generation

lock = Lock()

class ImageGenerator:
    def __init__(self, src=0):
      # initialize it with zeros to always have something to show. You can set it to None and check it outside before displaying
      self.frame = np.zeros((100,100,1))
      self.stopped = True

    def start(self):
     # checks if the generator is still running, to avoid two threads doing the same
     if not self.stopped:
       return
     self.stopped = False
     #Launches a thread to update itself
     Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()
     return self

    def update(self):
      # go until stop is called, you can set other criterias
      while True:
        if self.stopped:
          return
        # generate the image, this is equal to finalimage = generate_image() in your code
        image = np.random.randint(0,255, (600, 800, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        # this sleep is to simulate that it took longer to execute
        time.sleep(2)
        with lock:
          self.frame = image

    # if this changes the other thread will stop
    def stop(self):
      self.stopped = True

    # gets latest frame available  
    def get(self):
      return self.frame

# creates the object and start generating
imGen = ImageGenerator()
imGen.start()
# infinite loop to display the image, it can be stopped at any point with 'q'
while (True):
    cv2.imshow("Image", imGen.get())
    k = cv2.waitKey(50) & 0xFF
    if k == ord('q'):
      break;
# stops the generator and the other thread
imGen.stop()    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This way the image can be updated and OpenCV will display it as soon as possible, and still have some responsive GUI in which you can do other stuff (like key bindings).